# How to subtract 2 dates in oracle to get the result in hour and minute

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I want to subtract 2 dates and represent the result in hour and minute in one decimal figure.

I have the following table and I am doing it in this way but the result is not as desired.

There is some slight variation, I'm sure this is simple arithmetic but I'm not getting it right.

```
select start_time, end_time, (end_time-start_time)*24 from 
come_leav;
```

```
START_TIME          END_TIME            (END_TIME-START_TIME)*24    
------------------- ------------------- ------------------------      
21-06-2011 14:00:00 21-06-2011 16:55:00  2.9166667      
21-06-2011 07:00:00 21-06-2011 16:50:00  9.8333333      
21-06-2011 07:20:00 21-06-2011 16:30:00  9.1666667
```

I want the result (end_time-start_time) as below.

```
16:55- 14:00 = 2.55      
16:50-07:00 = 9.5      
16:30-7:20 = 9.1 and so on.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Expected result looks rather ridiculous.
It should be like this.

16:55- 14:00 = 2:55 or 2.92   
16:50-07:00 = 9:50  or 9.83
16:30-7:20 = 9:10   or 9.17

Comment: will i be able to get it in the form of 2.55. I am actually reporting time in and time out and calculating the differnce in hours and minutes. thanks.

Comment: I have to say, this is probably one of most well-written SQL questions I have seen on Stack Overflow. I know you've probably long-forgotten this, but I had to say it.

Answer (score 4):

```
SQL> edit
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select start_date
  2      , end_date
  3      , (24 * extract(day from (end_date - start_date) day(9) to second))
  4          + extract(hour from (end_date - start_date) day(9) to second)
  5          + ((1/100) * extract(minute from (end_date - start_date) day(9) to second)) as "HOUR.MINUTE"
  6* from t
SQL> /

START_DATE          END_DATE            HOUR.MINUTE
------------------- ------------------- -----------
21-06-2011 14:00:00 21-06-2011 16:55:00        2.55
21-06-2011 07:00:00 21-06-2011 16:50:00         9.5
21-06-2011 07:20:00 21-06-2011 16:30:00         9.1
```

It should be noted for those coming across this code that the decimal portions are ACTUAL minute differences, and not part of an hour. `.5`, therefore, represents `50 minutes`, not `30 minutes`.

Comment: Below is the result when i run this. But pls have a look at the last line it gives me 7.1 where as I need it to be 7.5 (14-6.50) without jeoparizing other figures. Appreciate your help START_TIME          END_TIME            HOUR.MINUTE
------------------- ------------------- ----
21-06-2011 14:00:00 21-06-2011 16:55:00        2.55
21-06-2011 07:00:00 21-06-2011 16:50:00         9.5
21-06-2011 07:20:00 21-06-2011 16:30:00         9.1
22-06-2011 07:20:00 22-06-2011 16:30:00         9.1
23-06-2011 07:20:00 23-06-2011 16:30:00         9.1
21-06-2011 06:50:00 21-06-2011 14:00:00         7.1

Comment: @Macky. That makes no sense. You asked for subtraction of time that would result in `hours.minutes`. (Which doesn't make much sense to start with.) 14:00 minus 6:50 is seven hours ten minutes or 7.1. Are you saying that you want 2:00 - 1:59 to be 0.41 for a one minute and 1:41 - 1:00 to be 0.41 for forty one minutes?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance  Great job deciphering what he wanted and the code above.  As a note on the code in the post, because of the OP's odd requirement, it should be noted the decimal depicts actual minutes, not fractional parts of an hour.  I submitted an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
round(to_number(end_time - start_time) * 24)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the result is not what I wanted. See below                                                             SQL> select to_number(end_time-start_time)*24 from come_leav;

TO_NUMBER(END_TIME-START_TIME)*24
---------------------------------
                        2.9166667
                        9.8333333
                        9.1666667
                        9.1666667
                        9.1666667
                        7.1666667

Comment: I don't have an oracle database installed, therefore I couldn't checked the query I gave. Sorry for incorrect/incomplete answer.

Comment: It's accurate in the sense that it gives the decimal equivalent of the minutes -- just have to multiply that portion by 60. Problem is the odd requirement where the OP needed it as `HH.MM`.

Comment: `FLOOR((end_time - start_time) * 24) || '.' || ROUND(((end_time - start_time) * 24) - FLOOR((end_time - start_time) * 24)*60)` is likely how the OP would need to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle represents dates as a number of days, so `(end_time-start_time)*24` gives you hours. Let's assume you have this number (eg. `2.9166667`) in `h` column. Then you can easily convert it to the format you want with: `FLOOR(h) + (h-FLOOR(h))/100*60`.

Example:

```
WITH diff AS (
    SELECT (TO_DATE('21-06-2011 16:55:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE('21-06-2011 14:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))*24 h
    FROM dual
) SELECT FLOOR(h) + (h-FLOOR(h))/100*60
FROM diff
```

In your case:

```
SELECT start_time, end_time,
    FLOOR((end_time-start_time)*24) + ((end_time-start_time)*24-FLOOR((end_time-start_time)*24))/100*60 AS hours_diff
FROM come_leav
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the time difference to beginning of the day then extract hours, minutes and seconds out of it in 24 hour format.

**NOTE:** be aware of days!

#### Example

###### SQL

```sql
    with w_dates as (
      select to_date('08/08/2023 01:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') date_start, 
             to_date('08/08/2023 02:23:45', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') date_end from dual)
    select floor(date_end-date_start) days, 
           to_char(trunc(sysdate) + sum(date_end-date_start),'HH24:MI:SS') hours_minutes_seconds 
      from w_dates;
```

###### Result

```
DAYS | HOURS_MINUTES_SECONDS
-----------------------------
   0 | 01:23:45
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    SELECT
    TRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(((86400*(end_time - start_time))/60)/60)-24*(trunc((((86400*(end_time - start_time))/60)/60)/24)),'00')) ||'.'||
    TRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC((86400*(end_time - start_time))/60)-60*(trunc(((86400*(end_time - start_time))/60)/60)),'00')) ||'.'  as duration
FROM come_leav;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am getting the results as desired but cant i get it without concatenation, I mean as a final result because I have to use this to calculate difference in time in and time out.

Comment: @Macky if you have to use it to calculate stuff, the results in your original post are correct. 1h30 is one hour and a *half*, a half is 0.5, so 1h30 = 1.5 hours.

Comment: Hi roslan, you are right but I want the calculation to be done as I requested b'coz I want to find the time difference between start time and end time. So I want the result as requested earlier i.e 16:55-14:00 to be 2.55 and not 2.916667. so please advise a simpler way to do it thankx...

Comment: @Macky, I have edited the post... replaced the : seperator with a . and removed the seconds from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: if you need a number, then

```
    trunc(end_date-start_date)*24+
    to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate)+(end_date-start_date),'HH24.MI'))
```

For string result, if delta is LESS THAN 24H:
I would go with

```
    to_char(trunc(sysdate)+(end_date-start_date),'HH24.MI')
```

or `...'HH24:MI:SS'`, but thats my personal preference.

for longer than 24H terms, I would prefix with

```
    trunc(end_date-start_date)||"days "||
    to_char(trunc(sysdate)+(end_date-start_date),'HH24.MI')
```

Yes, as oracle counts in days, with seconds precision, you are dealing with arithmetical problems. Once because you are only handling minutes (so you might round your number to `trunc(days*24*60+0.5)/24/60`), but the binary arithmetic imprecision on the number 1/24/60 might still cause you troubles.

Edit2.1:

```
    to_char(24*(trunc(end_date)-trunc(start_date))+to_number(to_char(end_date,'HH24.MI'))-to_number(to_char(start_date,'HH24.MI')),'99999.99')
```

But The result could be quite confusing for the average, as the decimal 7.50 would suggest seven and a half hour, or at least 7 hour 50 minutes, opposed to the elapsed time of 7 hours 10 minutes.

Comment: select start_time, end_time, to_char(trunc(sysdate)+(end_time-start_time),'HH24.MI') from come_leav;

S_TIME          E_TIME  T_C
21-06-2011 14:00:00 21-06-2011 16:55:00 02.55
21-06-2011 07:00:00 21-06-2011 16:50:00 09.50
21-06-2011 07:20:00 21-06-2011 16:30:00 09.10
22-06-2011 07:20:00 22-06-2011 16:30:00 09.10
23-06-2011 07:20:00 23-06-2011 16:30:00 09.10
21-06-2011 06:50:00 21-06-2011 14:00:00 07.10. Please have a look at the last result (14-06.50) returns 07.10 where as I want it as (14-06.50) = 7.5. Any suggestion how to overcome that.. Thanks a million for your help.

Comment: This is what i get, Seems to have fixed the last one but pls have a look at the first one it gives -88.45 instead of 2.55. Pls help I need to get it right. Appreciate..

START_TIME          END_TIME
--------- -------------------
TRUNC(END_TIME-START_TIME)+TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(END_TIME,'HH24.MI'))-TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(START_TI
--------------------------------------------------------------------
21-09-2011 14:00:00 21-06-2011 16:55:00  -88.45
21-06-2011 07:00:00 21-06-2011 16:50:00   9.5
23-06-2011 07:20:00 23-06-2011 16:30:00   9.1
21-06-2011 06:50:00 21-06-2011 14:00:00   7.5

Comment: Ok, made some mistake, 2.1 now works as your will. But couldnt get 2.55 as they are on different months, and end is smaller than start, so got to result in a big negative number. (If you remove the 24*(...)+ part, you'll get 2.55, but you shouldn't)

Comment: Hi @vmatyi, Sorry. Yes that date is on a different month. It has to be on the same month or I should say it will be on a same date. I am finding the difference by subtracting time_out from time_in to get in hr.min. This is for a data got from a time clock machine which tracks emp in and out times and to report tot hours and late hours. I am doing it this way.                                  return(trunc(:et_time-:st_time)+to_char(to_number(to_char(:et_time, 'HH24.MI'))-to_number(to_char(:st_time,'HH24.MI')),'9.99'));

Answer (score 0):

This query is very usefull for me and if any body want diffrence between start_date and end_date with time like HH:MI:SS please use this query.

```
SELECT
    TRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(((86400*(end_date - start_date))/60)/60)-24*(trunc((((86400(end_date - start_date))/60)/60)/24)),'00')) ||'.'||
    TRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC((86400*(actual_completion_date - actual_start_date))/60)-60*(trunc(((86400*(end_date - start_date))/60)/60)),'00')) ||'.'||
    TRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC((86400*(end_date - start_date)))-60*(trunc((86400*(end_date - actual_start_date))/60)),'00')) as duration  
FROM fnd_concurrent_requests;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very ugly way to do it, and this first part doesn't exactly question by the OP, but it gives a way to get results by subtracting 2 date fields -- in my case, the `CREATED_DATE` and today represented by `SYSDATE`:

```
SELECT FLOOR(ABS(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CREATED_DATE, SYSDATE)) / 12) || ' years, '  
|| (FLOOR(ABS(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CREATED_DATE, SYSDATE))) - 
   (FLOOR(ABS(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CREATED_DATE, SYSDATE)) / 12)) * 12) || ' months, '  
-- we take total days - years(as days) - months(as days) to get remaining days
|| FLOOR((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE) -      -- total days
   (FLOOR((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)/365)*12)*(365/12) -      -- years, as days
   -- this is total months - years (as months), to get number of months, 
   -- then multiplied by 30.416667 to get months as days (and remove it from total days)
   FLOOR(FLOOR(((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)/365)*12 - (FLOOR((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)/365)*12)) * (365/12)))  
|| ' days, '   
-- Here, we can just get the remainder decimal from total days minus 
-- floored total days and multiply by 24       
|| FLOOR(
     ((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)-(FLOOR(SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)))*24
   )
|| ' hours, ' 
-- Minutes just use the unfloored hours equation minus floored hours, 
-- then multiply by 60
|| ROUND(
       (
         (
           ((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)-(FLOOR(SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)))*24
         ) - 
         FLOOR((((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)-(FLOOR(SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)))*24))
       )*60
    )
|| ' minutes'  
AS AGE FROM MyTable`
```

It delivers the output as x years, x months, x days, x hours, x minutes.  It could be reformatted however you like by changing the concatenated strings.

To more directly answer the question, I've gone ahead and written out how to get the total hours with minutes as `hours.minutes`:

```
select  
((FLOOR(end_date - start_date))*24)
|| '.' ||
ROUND(
       (
         (
           ((end_date - start_date)-(FLOOR(end_date - start_date)))*24
         ) - 
         FLOOR((((end_date - start_date)-(FLOOR(end_date - start_date)))*24))
       )*60
    )
from 
come_leav;
```

Answer (score -2):

you can work with the extract:

```
SELECT start_time, end_time, extract(HOUR FROM end_time-start_time) || '.' || extract(MINUTE FROM end_time-start_time)  
From come_leav;
```

Comment: i am getting the following error: SQL> SELECT start_time, end_time, extract(HOUR FROM end_time-start_time) || '.' || extract(MINUTE FROM end_time-start_time) From come_leav; SELECT start_time, end_time, extract(HOUR FROM end_time-start_time) || '.' || extract(MINUTE FROM end_time-start_time) From come_leav * ERROR at line 1: ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source

Comment: @roselan I get the same error as Macky. Would've been great if it worked, or could be made to work.