# Days between two dates

Tags: oracle, function, date, difference

I appreciate this has probably been asked many times before, but from reading through them I am unable to find a solution for what I want.

It is quite simple. I want to calculate the number of days that are between two dates using an oracle function.

Date_Reported and Date_Closed are the two respected days. But I also need to put this into a package at the end of the day which I feel I can do, I'm just struggling with the function.

Would somebody be able to give me a structure to this so that I can assemble the function to be used in my package? I'm still a novice with Oracle Features.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460266/how-to-subtract-2-dates-in-oracle-to-get-the-result-in-hour-and-minute

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
SELECT Trunc( t.date1 - t.date2) AS days
  FROM myTable t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
create or replace function diffdate (date1 in date, date2 in date)
    return number is
begin
    return date2-date1;
end;
/

select diffdate (sysdate,to_date('20100827','yyyymmdd')) from dual;

28.5796412037037
```