# Subtract dates in format mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: plsql

How would one subtract dates in a mm/dd/yyyy format so I can return a whole number in days?(exclude time in my columns)

This is what I have so far:

```
(A.START_DT - A.END_DT) AS DaysHere


  Start Date               End Date
11/6/2012 10:33:25 AM      12/17/2013
```

Comment: What was the issue with `SELECT (A.START_DT - A.END_DT) FROM yourtable` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subtract 2 dates in oracle to get the result in hour and minute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460266/how-to-subtract-2-dates-in-oracle-to-get-the-result-in-hour-and-minute)

Comment: @SameerMirji It returns results but I would like to subtract mm/dd/yyyy only and not subtract time.

Comment: `SELECT (to_date(A.START_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy') - to_date(A.END_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy')) FROM yourtable A` will do it.

Comment: @SameerMirji I'm getting an error. "A non numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"

Comment: @SameerMirji got it to work...  (TO_DATE(a.start_Dt, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE(a.end_dt, 'DD-MM-YYYY')) as dayshere

Comment: if `a.start_dt` and `a.end_dt` are `date` columns then use `trunc`: `select trunc(a.start_dt) - trunc(a.end_dt) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`to_date`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) to specify the format.

```
DB(ADMIN)=> 
  select 
    to_date(start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mi:SS AM') 
    - to_date(end_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') dayshere 
  from so;
 DAYSHERE
----------
     -406
```