# SQLite vs. Oracle - Calculating date differences - hours

Tags: oracle, sqlite, date, date-difference

I wonder if anyone has seen this, and if there is a solution, or if I'm just not doing something right.  I'm trying to get the hours difference between now and a "created date" in a database record - not trying to get the total hours, but the hours left after you get rid of total days, so you can output that something is x days, x hours old.

**Initial Givens**

Let's use a `SYSDATE`, or "now", of `12/6/2016 6:41 PM`.

Let's say I have an Oracle table and a SQLite table that we will call `MyTable`.    In it, I have a `CREATED_DATE` field with dates stored in local time:

```
CREATED_DATE
------------
1/20/2015 1:35:17 PM
6/9/2016 3:10:46 PM
```

Both tables are identical, except that it is of type `DATE` in Oracle, but in SQLite, you have to store a date as a string with a format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.  But each table's values are the same.

I start off getting the total days difference between "now" and the dates. I can subtract out the integer days from the decimal days and get the hours I need.

**Total Days - Oracle**

If I do this in Oracle, to give me the total days difference:
`SELECT (SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE) FROM MyTable`

I get `686.211284...` for the first one and `180.144976...` for the second.

**Total Days - SQLite**

If I do this using SQLite to give me the total days difference, the first one is pretty close, but the second is really off:
`SELECT (julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) FROM MyTable`

I get `686.212924....` for the first one and `180.188283...` for the second.

**Problem**

I added `'utc'` on the SQLite query because I know that `julianday()` uses GMT.  Otherwise the hours were about 6 hours off.  The problem is they are now 1 hour off, but not all of the time.  The first result gives the right number of hours difference:  5, in both cases:

```
.211284 x 24 = 5.07 hours
.212924 x 24 = 5.11 hours
```

When I floor those values, it gives me the result I need.

With that second one, though, here is what I get:

```
.144976 x 24 = 3.479 hours
.188283 x 24 = 4.519 hours
```

A HUGE difference - a whole hour different!  Can anyone help with why this is, and if there's a way to fix it/make it accurate?

**Getting the hours**

This is the code I'm using to get the hours.  I have confirmed the hours I get when I use Oracle are correct by using a calculator to double-check it.  For that, I use:

```
SELECT FLOOR(((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)-(FLOOR(SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)))*24) FROM MyTable
```

I am currently trying to get the hours in SQLite using a similar setup:

```
(((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) - 
CAST ((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) AS INTEGER))*24)
```

I've left off the "flooring", or integer casting, of the SQLite result, for now, on purpose.  Both queries basically take the total days minus the integer total days to get the decimal remainder (which is the portion of a day that represents hours) and multiplies it by 24.

It is funny, though, because I am using the same query above for the whole hours minus a casted version of it for the integer hours, leaving the decimal portion for minutes, and multiplying that by 60 and it comes out perfectly for the minutes.

**Screenshot: Side by Side Comparison**

This was taken at `12/6/2016 7:20 PM`, with SQLite shown in my application on the left, Oracle query being done in Oracle SQL Developer on the right:

[image]

Comment: I think I know what's going on.  It's only from April - October that the extra hour is present.  I believe this is due to Daylight Savings Time.  Anyone know a good way to correct it?

Comment: That's why timestamp are, when you can, so useful : no +/- zone nor daylight saving hours, you just choose the format and adjustments when you print-it

Comment: Unfortunately, I saw Wernfried's `TIMESTAMP` example below and that's the opposite of what I want to do, at least for Oracle.  It seems to actually use a timezone, and my app is really not dependent on that, as it will live off the grid and never be connected to someone in a different zone than those creating items.  The way I was doing my Oracle query was correct, for my purposes: `SELECT (SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE) FROM MyTable`, which is the same as Wernfried's `TO_DATE` example, just without the `TO_DATE` syntax, since both are dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you missed one important information: Which value do you consider as being correct? Do you have to consider Daylight-Saving hours or not?

Start with **Oracle**:

I assume data type of column `CREATED_DATE` is `DATE`. `SYSDATE` returns also a `DATE` value. `DATE` value does not have any time zone (i.e. Daylight-Saving time settings) information.

Assuming **now** is 2016-12-06 06:00:00:

```
SELECT 
   TO_DATE('2016-12-06 06:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
   - TO_DATE('2016-06-09 06:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM dual;
```

returns exactly 180 Days.

If you have to consider Daylight-Saving time you have to use data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`), see this example:

```
SELECT 
   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2016-12-06 06:00:00 Europe/Zurich','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') 
   - TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2016-06-09 06:00:00 Europe/Zurich','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') 
FROM dual;
```

Result is `+180 01:00:00.000000`, i.e. 180 days and 1 hour.

It depends on your requirement which one you have to use. In general I would recommend to use `TIMESTAMP`, resp. `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` rather than `DATE`, because there you can simply use [EXTRACT(datetime)](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639) to get the hours and you don't have to fiddle with `FLOOR` and such stuff:

```
 SELECT 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP - CREATED_DATE) AS diff_hours 
FROM MyTable;
```

Note, `LOCALTIMESTAMP` returns a `TIMESTAMP` value, use `SYSTIMESTAMP`, resp. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get current time as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value.

Now consider **SQLite**:

**Update**

Actually `julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')` gives correct result - or let's call it *"precise result"*. It takes Daylight-Saving shifts into account. For example difference of '2016-10-31 00:00:00' - '2016-10-30 00:00:00' (European times) is 25 hours - not 24 hours!

Now, you like to ignore Daylight-Saving shifts in your calculation. For Oracle this was simple, use `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data types instead of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, then you are done.

SQLite always considers time zones and Daylight-Saving shifts, you have to make some hacks to bypass it. 
I got some time to make a few tests and I found several ways to do it.

Following methods are all working on my machine (Swiss time with Daylight-Saving settings, +01:00 resp. +02:00).

- `julianday('now', 'localtime') - julianday(CREATED_DATE)`
- `julianday(datetime('now', 'localtime')||'Z') - julianday(CREATED_DATE||'Z')`

See test cases:

```
create table t (CREATED_DATE DATE);

insert into t values (datetime('2015-06-01 00:00:00'));
insert into t values (datetime('2015-12-01 00:00:00'));
insert into t values (datetime('2016-06-01 00:00:00'));
insert into t values (datetime('2016-12-01 00:00:00'));

select datetime('now', 'localtime') as now, 
    created_date, 
    julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc') as wrong_delta_days,
    strftime('%j %H:%M:%S', datetime('0000-01-01T00:00:00', '+'||(julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc'))||' day', '-1 day')) as wrong_delta,    

    strftime('%j %H:%M:%S', datetime('0000-01-01T00:00:00', '+'||(julianday('now', 'localtime') - julianday(CREATED_DATE))||' day', '-1 day')) as delta_1, 
    strftime('%j %H:%M:%S',
       datetime('now', 'localtime', 
          '-'||strftime('%Y', CREATED_DATE)||' year', 
          '-'||strftime('%j', CREATED_DATE)||' day', 
          '-'||strftime('%H', CREATED_DATE)||' hour', 
          '-'||strftime('%M', CREATED_DATE)||' minute', 
          '-'||strftime('%S', CREATED_DATE)||' second'
         )) as delta_2,
    strftime('%j %H:%M:%S', datetime('0000-01-01T00:00:00', '+'||(julianday(datetime('now', 'localtime')||'Z') - julianday(CREATED_DATE||'Z'))||' day', '-1 day')) as delta_3
from t;


now                 | CREATED_DATE        | wrong_delta_days | wrong_delta  | delta_1      | delta_2      | delta_3
2016-12-08 08:34:08 | 2015-06-01 00:00:00 | 556.398711088113 | 190 09:34:08 | 190 08:34:08 | 190 08:34:08 | 190 08:34:08
2016-12-08 08:34:08 | 2015-12-01 00:00:00 | 373.357044421136 | 007 08:34:08 | 007 08:34:08 | 007 08:34:08 | 007 08:34:08
2016-12-08 08:34:08 | 2016-06-01 00:00:00 | 190.398711088113 | 190 09:34:08 | 190 08:34:08 | 190 08:34:08 | 190 08:34:08
2016-12-08 08:34:08 | 2016-12-01 00:00:00 | 7.35704442113638 | 007 08:34:08 | 007 08:34:08 | 007 08:34:08 | 007 08:34:08
```

I used `strftime('%j %H:%M:%S', datetime('0000-01-01T00:00:00', ..., '-1 day'))` just for formatting purpose, it is not suitable for deltas which span over more than 1 year.

Comment: As I said in the original question, I considered the Oracle side to be correct. I just wanted a straight calculation against the time, no matter when in the year it is, and timezones don't matter because, even though my app will be distributed to many global locations, each item created within it will *only* be created by members of that timezone-it will not be accessible over the internet.  If today is `12/6/2016 00:00:00`, and the item was created on `6/9/2016 12:00:00`, they should be 180 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes apart. So I don't want timestamps-my Oracle subtraction was just fine for me.

Comment: And whenever I use `EXTRACT`, I always get `ERROR at line 1: ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source`, so I wouldn't recommend using that to anyone.  See downvoted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460266/how-to-subtract-2-dates-in-oracle-to-get-the-result-in-hour-and-minute

Comment: And on the SQLite side, as I said in the original question, I needed to add `'utc'` to the `CREATED_DATE` side because you are wrong -- `julianday('now')` does NOT return a value to my local time - it subtracts my local time from the Julian Day with the GMT timezone - `the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C.` http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html .  When I did `SELECT julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE)`, my answers were off by either 5 hours (for dates outside DST time) or 6 hours (for dates inside the DST range).

Comment: You can use EXTRACT only on `TIMESTAMP` or `INTERVAL` data types not from `DATE` or NUMBER (of days). Have a look at [Matrix of Datetime Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#g196492) to see when you get which data type.

Comment: Except the matrix says absolutely nothing about `EXTRACT`, but it might have it's purpose.  I never use `TIMESTAMP` (because I don't want timezone info or the extra hour) and have never used `INTERVAL`, so it's probably why I could never use `EXTRACT`.  I prefer working directly with the `DATE`, itself. Less complicated.  And since I don't want the `TIMESTAMP` hours info, I wouldn't be using `EXTRACT`, then, anyway, it sounds like.  Glad to know `EXTRACT` actually DOES work, after all, in some kind of scenario, though.

Comment: Oh, and just to avoid any confusion, I meant my first comment to compare the same dates you did, `12/6/2016 00:00:00` vs. `6/9/2016 00:00:00`... midnight vs. midnight = 0 hours.... not midnight vs. 12 noon, like I had up there... curse SO and their 5 minute editing rule...

Comment: The SQLite query you gave actually required one more set of parenthesis around it all for me to run it.  When I did, I got 321 for my first item, 180 for my second.  This is not the number of days - I have the number of days.  I need to get an accurate number of hours.  I do believe you're on to something with how you said `for today [it] uses winter time (i.e. no Daylight-Saving) no matter if CREATED_DATE value is in summer or winter`, but I do know it must be converting `CREATED_DATE` to UTC just fine because without it, my hours are 5 or 6 hours off.

Comment: Thanks for that `0.0` trick.  Unfortunately, if this result is in days with the decimal indicating hours, it is worse than I had.  For my first date, it claims 321.97645 days, and so the decimal portion * 24 will give 23 hours.  My Oracle subtraction gives 22.  For my second date, it gives 180.96015 days, which is 23 hours.  My Oracle result is 21 hours.

Comment: I tried your trick of `julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE||'Z')`, but it doesn't seem to like that.  I got the 5 or 6 hours off, again.  I'm just going to use `julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')` and I'll work on a converter for when the date `.IsDaylightSavingTime()` in the C# code to update the Age column manually in the DataTable that binds to the ListView, by subtracting an hour in those cases.

Comment: Sorry, but your statement that `It takes Daylight-Saving shifts into account` is correct & incorrect at the same time.  You are right that you get 25 hours, and that this is due to the DST shift. For me, as you figured out, this is not a *correct* result because I want it to be 24 hours, not 25. I don't care that something was created at noon on a day during DST, and now it's winter and I'm checking it at noon, and so my clocks are set back an hour, creating the extra hour. I don't want it to be an extra hour old when comparing NOON to NOON!

Comment: You must have missed my query in my question.  I was already using `julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')` when I got this issue.  So that one is not correct for adjusting for DST.  It will give an extra hour when it is a DST date, and I'm comparing it against today, which is non-DST.

Comment: I thought `julianday('now', 'localtime') - julianday(CREATED_DATE)` was basically the same thing, just that instead of adjusting the `CREATED_DATE` to UTC, to match the UTC `julianday('now')`, you set `'now'` to local because `CREATED_DATE` is local.  But this one actually DOES work.

Comment: I found that `julianday(datetime('now', 'localtime')||'Z') - julianday(CREATED_DATE||'Z')` is also working. You've learned that if you have them in the same format, (local vs. local, or 'Z' vs. 'Z') they work! I don't know why there seems to be a difference when using the implicit UTC calc of `julianday('now')` vs. `julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')`.  Both should be UTC, but that one does NOT work when comparing today vs. a DST date, and was the query I started with.  Remove that one and I'll upvote your post. :)  Btw, those ones that work-I tested against items over a year old & they work fine.

Comment: Right, was a typo from my side.

Comment: I tried `strftime('%H', datetime('now', 'localtime', '-'||strftime('%H', CREATED_DATE)||' hour'))` from your post. Being over a year old or under a year, DST or non-DST, it didn't matter. I had good results from most of my 14 dates, but bad results from some others-and there was no pattern among the bad (which gave `+1` hours). These dates gave an extra hour: `1/20/2015 1:35:17 PM`, `7/29/2015 11:40:32 AM`, `10/3/2016 1:51:05 PM`, and `10/13/2016 12:52:09 PM`. These dates gave good results:  `3/20/2015 2:16:30 PM`, `2/3/2015 1:28:36 PM`, `4/14/2016 8:30:24 AM`, `6/16/2016 9:29:41 AM`.

Comment: So, in short, I don't recommend `strftime`. But at least we have 2 good queries, with consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I get your problem, it seem the daylight change was lost for SQLite, or to be exact, that you need to specify this change on the save (as it's a string and not a *true* date field / transparent-timestamp).

When you generate (? if you do) the date, make it full UTC with time zone explicit and not local implicit :

> [**SQLite Date / Time**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)
>
> Formats 2 through 10 may be optionally followed by a timezone
>   indicator of the form "[+-]HH:MM" or just "Z". The date and time
>   functions use UTC or "zulu" time internally, and so the "Z" suffix is
>   a no-op. Any non-zero "HH:MM" suffix is subtracted from the indicated
>   date and time in order to compute zulu time. For example, all of the
>   following time strings are equivalent:
>
> ```
> 2013-10-07 08:23:19.120
> 2013-10-07T08:23:19.120Z
> 2013-10-07 04:23:19.120-04:00
> ```

To be honest, the SQLite with `utc` is not wrong when it come to "forget" the daylight change, as UTC don't move (it's chronometric physicals hours). If you told him everything is at the same UTC time-zone, it'll just make a simple subtract and don't give a f*icus* about your daylight.

Don't your `julianday('now')` take a `'UTC'` too ?
(sorry if I don't get it, I'll take a second look tomorrow)

Comment: Thanks. Conversion from Oracle I do is `DateTime.Parse(oraDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` to store in SQLite. Seems to grab it & do calculations just fine in the format I saved it in, except for the problem in my post. When I tried putting a `-05:00` on the date/time string and saving it with that, it gives me errors when running my query and trying to fill a DataSet with my SQLiteDataAdapter, saying `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`-so even though it's in the documentation, I don't think the last one is accurate. The way I'm storing it is just like the first one.

Comment: I'm in the Eastern U.S., so GMT is +5 from me.  The `julianday('now')` is comparing against UTC, already, so it already gets +5 hours than it should.  I was making `CREATED_DATE` as UTC to compensate.  If you make it `julianday('now','utc')` without UTC on `CREATED_DATE`, then the difference is +10 hours.  If you put UTC on both, then my compensation I was doing on `CREATED_DATE` is negated and it gets +5 hours, again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't at all the ideal way to do this, but I solved this myself using a compensator function in my C# application that was pulling the SQLite values.  It actually occurred to me after I wrote this that I could've just re-done the date subtraction in C# and over-wrote my Age field!  But since I just needed to modify the hours (and days, if hours was 0 and it was a DST date) for the given condition, I just used this.

So I have a class that will provide a DataTable of results based on the query I provide to a public static string variable in that class and another function I call.  Then, I call `BindTable()` to bind that table to the `ListView` in my WPF app to display the information.

I pull my DataTable in by calling `ADOClass.adoDataTable`.  Once I have the DataTable, I just iterate through the rows, store the Created Date as a variable, and the Age string (which I use the function to update as necessary) as a variable.  If the Created Date meets the `.IsDaylightSavingTime()` condition, it has to get an hour subtracted.  If the Age was say, 0 hours (and some odd minutes) old, we have to set the days back one day, and the hours to 23.

```
private void BindTable()
{            
    DataTable dt = ADOClass.adoDataTable;

    if (!Oracle_DAL.ConnTest()) // if no Oracle connection, SQLite is running and it needs DST correction
    {
        int oldHours = 0;
        int newHours = 0;
        int oldDays = 0;
        int newDays = 0;
        string ageCell = String.Empty;
        string hoursString = String.Empty;
        string daysString = String.Empty;
        string crDate = String.Empty;

        if (dt != null && dt.Rows != null)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    crDate = dr["CREATED_DATE"] != null ? dr["CREATED_DATE"].ToString() : String.Empty;
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(crDate))
                    {
                        DateTime createdDate = DateTime.Parse(crDate);
                        if (createdDate.IsDaylightSavingTime())
                        {
                            ageCell = dr["AGE"] != null ? dr["AGE"].ToString() : String.Empty;
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ageCell))
                            {
                                hoursString = ageCell.Split(',')[3];
                                hoursString = hoursString.TrimStart(' ');
                                oldHours = int.Parse(hoursString.Split(' ')[0]);

                                if (oldHours == 0)
                                {
                                    newHours = 23;
                                    daysString = ageCell.Split(',')[2];
                                    daysString = daysString.TrimStart(' ');
                                    oldDays = int.Parse(daysString.Split(' ')[0]);
                                    oldDays--;
                                    newDays = oldDays;
                                    ageCell = ageCell.Replace(daysString, newDays.ToString() + " days");
                                    dr["AGE"] = ageCell;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    oldHours--;
                                    newHours = oldHours;                                    
                                }
                                dr["AGE"] = ageCell.Replace(hoursString, newHours.ToString() + " hours");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                        
            }
        }
    }

    lstData.DataContext = dt;  // binds to my ListView's grid
}
```

(*NOTE:*  I realized later that, because I tested this function on a non-DST day, and this was meant to fix issues with DST dates, that when it becomes DST again, I believe things will change.  I think I'd end up having to add an hour to my results for non-DST dates to make it work, at that point.  So this would have to have an additional check if `DateTime.Now` conforms to `.IsDaylightSavingTime()` in order to know what to do.  I may re-visit this post at that time.)

And in case anyone is curious.....
Here is the full query I was running in Oracle:

```
SELECT CREATED_DATE, (SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE) AS TOTALDAYS, 
FLOOR(ABS(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CREATED_DATE, SYSDATE)) / 12) || ' years, '  
|| (FLOOR(ABS(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CREATED_DATE, SYSDATE))) - 
   (FLOOR(ABS(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CREATED_DATE, SYSDATE)) / 12)) * 12) || ' months, '  
-- we take total days - years(as days) - months(as days) to get remaining days
|| FLOOR((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE) -      -- total days
   (FLOOR((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)/365)*12)*(365/12) -      -- years, as days
   -- this is total months - years (as months), to get number of months, 
   -- then multiplied by 30.416667 to get months as days (and remove it from total days)
   FLOOR(FLOOR(((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)/365)*12 - (FLOOR((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)/365)*12)) * (365/12)))  
|| ' days, '   
-- Here, we can just get the remainder decimal from total days minus 
-- floored total days and multiply by 24       
|| FLOOR(
     ((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)-(FLOOR(SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)))*24
   )
|| ' hours, ' 
-- Minutes just use the unfloored hours equation minus floored hours, 
-- then multiply by 60
|| ROUND(
       (
         (
           ((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)-(FLOOR(SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)))*24
         ) - 
         FLOOR((((SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)-(FLOOR(SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE)))*24))
       )*60
    )
|| ' minutes'  
AS AGE FROM MyTable`
```

And this is my final, full query for SQLite from my application:

```
    private static readonly string mainqueryCommandTextSQLite = "SELECT " + 
        "CREATED_DATE, " +
        " (julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) AS TOTALDAYS, " +
        //            " (((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE))/365)*12) || ' total months, ' || " +
        //            " ((CAST ((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE))/365 AS INTEGER))*12) || ' years as months, ' || " +

        // Provide years, months
        " CAST ((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc'))/365 AS INTEGER) || ' years, ' || " +
        " CAST (((((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc'))/365)*12) - (CAST ((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc'))/365 AS INTEGER)*12)) AS INTEGER)  || ' months, ' " +

        // Provide days
        "|| ((CAST ((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) AS INTEGER) - " +  // total number of days
        " (CAST ((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc'))/365 AS INTEGER)*365) ) -" + // years in days  
        " CAST((30.41667 * ((CAST ((((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc'))/365)*12) AS INTEGER)) - ((CAST ((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) / 365 AS INTEGER)) * 12))) AS INTEGER)) " + // days of remaining months using total months - months from # of floored years * (365/12)
        " || ' days, ' " +

        // BUG:  These next two do not get accurate hours during DST months (March - Nov)
        // This gives hours
        "|| CAST ((((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) - " +
        " CAST ((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) AS INTEGER))*24) AS INTEGER) " +

        // This gives hours.minutes
        //"|| (((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) - CAST ((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) AS INTEGER))*24) " +

        // This gives days.hours, but taking the decimal and multiplying by 24 to get actual hours 
        // gives an incorrect result
        //"|| ((" +
        //        "(0.0 + strftime('%S', 'now', 'localtime') " +
        //        "+ 60*strftime('%M', 'now', 'localtime') " +
        //        "+ 24*60*strftime('%H', 'now', 'localtime') " +
        //        "+ 24*60*60*strftime('%j', 'now', 'localtime')) - " +
        //        "(strftime('%S', CREATED_DATE) " +
        //        "+ 60*strftime('%M', CREATED_DATE) " +
        //        "+ 24*60*strftime('%H', CREATED_DATE) " +
        //        "+ 24*60*60*strftime('%j', CREATED_DATE)) " +
        //    ")/60/60/24) " +
        "|| ' hours, ' " +

        // Provide minutes
        "|| CAST (ROUND(((((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) - CAST ((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) AS INTEGER))*24) - " +
        "(CAST((((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) - CAST((julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')) AS INTEGER)) * 24) AS INTEGER)))*60) AS INTEGER)" +
        "|| ' minutes' " +
        " AS AGE FROM MyTable";
```

And new screenshot, showing everything matching (except total days, which I can alter by just subtracting 1/24 from in my C# function and update the same way, for the DST dates):

[image]

**UPDATE**

Since Wernfried found 2 queries in SQLite that negate the need for this function, I'm going to accept that answer for how to really solve this issue:

For Oracle -

- `SELECT (SYSDATE - CREATED_DATE) FROM MyTable`

or using `to_date` format syntax is good for getting the days.hours, and doing conversions.  Taking the decimal portion and multiplying by 24 is good for hours and is independent of DST, like I wanted.  See above for full query I used for formatting into years, months, days, hours, and minutes.

For SQLite -

As Wernfried found, either of these will work:

•    `julianday('now', 'localtime') - julianday(CREATED_DATE)`

•    `julianday(datetime('now', 'localtime')||'Z') - julianday(CREATED_DATE||'Z')`

And this avoids the need for my function above.

If you use:

•    `julianday('now') - julianday(CREATED_DATE, 'utc')`

like I have in the earlier code, above, then you would need my DST compensator function, farther above.